# Where to store html files in iOs app?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I've recently switched to working on an iOS app from Android, and am wondering where I should store the HTML files I'll be using in a WebView. Within an Android project, I've stored these files under the assets directory, but am not sure of the standard within an iOS app. Is there a standard? I'll be loading this jQuery mobile html file into a UIWebView. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XCode will store the html file in the application bundle.

Simply put the HTML file into your XCode project, in the "SUpporting Files" group usually, but it doesn't really matter.  At build time, XCode will put it in the bundle.  When you want to retrieve it:

```
NSURL* url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Would you know how to achieve the above in SWIFT?

Comment: by SWIFT, i mean the new programming language introduced by Apple and available in xcode 6 beta.